# Calling a function from another python file takes 15 seconds, compared to running it in the same module

Tags: python, tkinter, module

So, in an effort to refactor my code into a more modular project, i decided to export some of my most used functions, method and classes to separate py modules, so that i can simply "from x import y" and then use method y instead of copy-pasting the code (yes, i know that's horrible, but when you get "implement this yesterday" requests there is only so much you can do".

As an example, i often have to scan COM ports in my system and pick one or more, so i created this module:

```
from serial.tools import list_ports
from serial import Serial, SerialException
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial


def COMScanner():
    allports = []
    ports = list_ports.comports()
    for port, desc, hwid in sorted(ports):
        hwid = hwid.split(" SER")[0]
        # print("{}: {} [{}]".format(port, desc, hwid)) #DBG
        try:
            s = Serial(port)
            s.close()
            state = "FREE"
        except (OSError, SerialException):
            state = "BUSY"
            pass

        allports.append([port, hwid, state])

    return allports


def targetSelector(COMS):
    global sel_com
    sel_com = None
    # Once all COM ports are detected, if there are more than one, the user must pick one
    # to connect to the testing board, the user must click the button with the name of
    # the desired COM port and dismiss the dialog
    if COMS and len(COMS) > 1:
        COMSelector = tk.Tk()
        baseWidth = 8 * len("".join(max(COMS, key=len)))
        baseHeight = 35 * len(COMS)
        finalWidth = baseWidth + 10
        finalHeight = baseHeight  # * len(COMS)
        screen_width = COMSelector.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = COMSelector.winfo_screenheight()
        x_coordinate = int((screen_width / 2) - (finalWidth / 2))
        y_coordinate = int((screen_height / 2) - (finalHeight / 2))

        COMSelector.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(finalWidth, finalHeight, x_coordinate, y_coordinate))
        COMSelector.update_idletasks()
        COMSelector.title("Select Target")

        def save_action(selection):
            global sel_com, user_pass
            sel_com = str(selection)
            COMSelector.destroy()

        for id, COM in enumerate(COMS):
            COM_HANDLE = str(COM[0])
            COM_PID = str(COM[1])
            COM_STATE = str(COM[2])
            action = partial(save_action, COM_HANDLE)
            COMLabel = tk.Label(master=COMSelector, text=COM_PID, borderwidth=0.5, relief="solid")
            COMButton = tk.Button(master=COMSelector,
                                  text=("[" + COM_STATE + "] " + COM_HANDLE),
                                  command=action
                                  )
            if COM_STATE == "FREE":
                COMButton.config(state="active")
            else:
                COMButton.config(state="disabled")

            COMButton.grid(row=id, column=0, pady=5, padx=5, sticky="WE")
            COMLabel.grid(row=id, column=1, pady=5, padx=5, sticky="WE")
        COMSelector.mainloop()

    else:
        sel_com = COMS[0]
    try:
        return sel_com
    except:
        return "No target selected."
```

A typical usage might be, use COMScanner() to get the relevant port info and then targetSelector() to display the UI and let the user choose.

By defining the functions inside my program, both functions execute instantly (as expected)

By instead creating a module, in a folder I.E. "Snippets\COMSelector.py" and then using something like

```
from Snippets import COMSelector

[...]
start_time datetime.now()
available_COMS = COMSelector.COMScanner()
target = COMSelector.targetSelector(available_COMS)
print(datetime.now() - start_time)
```

with only one COM interface connected to the system, to eliminate the human clicking speed factor

i get 0:00:15.245072

Since i'm a beginner, i might be missing something crucial, please help!

Comment: First of all you could time both function calls separately to narrow down which one became slower (or if both became).

Comment: Tried that already, inexplicably, both functions are super slow, i tried something different, i implemented a if __name__ == "__main__": clause in the COMSelector file, and tried running it from cmd, it's blazing fast, the issue seems to be related to the import itself, rather than the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There apparently was an issue with my USB controller, rebooting didn't fix it, had to disable and re-enable the driver in my device manager, somehow it took a really long time executing the
"from serial.tools import list_ports" and
"from serial import Serial, SerialException" lines

about 7.4 - 7.5s each, not only that, each time i tried importing anything from the pyserial module it took that long.

i have no idea what caused this but, it's fixed now, marking as solved.